# How to know that which requests run in sync with the browser's execution thread, and which run out of sync?

Tags: manual-testing, jmeter, performance

From the developer tool, how can we find out which requests run in sync with the browser's execution thread, and which run out of sync in the webpage? and 
To check the performance of website which requests should be included for the performance testing of the website?

Comment: We need alot more info to help you there.  It depends on the way the application is built.  I would suggest opening your browser client tool where you can pull out traffic and get an image of that attached in here as well as specify more about the application under test with reference to specific targets and what your definition for "in sync" and "out of sync" is to be sure everyone is understanding your full intent

Comment: If we take an example of google.com. Then from developer tool how can we know which are dependent requests and which are independent requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach should be the following:

1. Configure your HTTP Request samplers to download so called "embedded resources" from HTML pages, this will simulate real browsers behavior (1 main request to the HTML page followed by parallel requests to download images, scripts and styles). It can be done using [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) configuration element.

   [image: JMeter HTTP Request Defaults]

   here you can also exclude external resources to focus only on the application you are testing at the moment
2. Add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to represent the browser cache as real browsers download these images, scripts and styles only once, on subsequent requests the resources are being returned from the disk cache.
3. If there are any dependent requests originating i.e. from [AJAX calls](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) they need to be added manually

See [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) article for more details.

So in general there is always **one main call** followed by parallel calls to embedded resources and JavaScript-driven chained calls (if any)